# bootstrap 4 class "text-center": text won´t center in row 1 but in row 2 its working

Tags: class, bootstrap-4

I am having a weird issue with the text-cent class in my footer.
I put two rows in a div and gave that div the class "text-center". The weird thing is, that it won´t center the text in the first row, but in the second row it works fine. Am I being stupid? I am not seeing the issue here, so I´d be thankful if someone looked at my code and told me what´s wrong.
I am just learning how to code, so please be gentle with me.

```
    <div class="row">
        <a><small> Impressum: © by Peter & Eva Fenz - Webdesign by Eva Fenz - Fenz Werbung, A-9762 Weissensee - Tel.: ... - <a href="mailto:...">Email: xxx@xxx.at</a></small></a> 
    </div>

    <div class="row"><a><small>Disclaimer: Diese Webpräsenz beinhaltet keine offiziellen Darstellungen der Gemeinde Weissensee.Alle hier veröffentlichten Inhalte sind ausschließlich privater Natur und sind von den jeweiligen Betrieben und Privatpersonen selbst zu verantworten. Nachrichten an die Gemeinde Weissensee werden selbstverständlich weitergeleitet.</small></a></div>

</div>
```

I tried different classes like "text-center" "text-justify" and "text-lg-center" which is the current class.

Answer (score 3):

You have some incorrect closing tags. Also you should not have nested `a` tags

Also `col` classes are missing inside `row` divs

Check this.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col">
        <small> Impressum: © by Peter &amp; Eva Fenz - Webdesign by Eva Fenz - Fenz Werbung, A-9762 Weissensee - Tel.: ... - <a href="mailto:...">Email: xxx@xxx.at</a></small>
 </div>
  </div>

    <div class="row text-center">
      <div>
        <a><small>Disclaimer: Diese Webpräsenz beinhaltet keine offiziellen Darstellungen der Gemeinde Weissensee.Alle hier veröffentlichten Inhalte sind ausschließlich privater Natur und sind von den jeweiligen Betrieben und Privatpersonen selbst zu verantworten. Nachrichten an die Gemeinde Weissensee werden selbstverständlich weitergeleitet.</small></a>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: wow, thank you so much Kiranvj for your quick answer! It is working now!
Thank you again!